# BAT file – use bracket as delim

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to use brackets (and space character) as delimiters in BAT file loop, but result is only error message on command line – `^(^)"" was unexpected at this time.`

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=" ^(^)"" %%a in ('status') do if "%%b"=="my_text" echo %%a
```

Can someone elaborate on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=() " %%a in ('status') do if "%%b"=="my_text" echo %%a
```

Comment: to include the Space as delimiter:  ...delims= ()"... does not work, instead ...delims=() " DOES work (note the position of the Space)